# Three EFI disks have started showing up on my desktop. What are these and can I eject them

Tags: macos

Several weeks ago three icons that look like a disk have started showing up on my desktop. All three have the name EFI. When I right-click on them and 'get info' they all three have a format as MS-DOS (FAT 32) and all three have the same creation date of Dec31, 1969. What are these and can I eject them. Will they stay ejected? If not how do I keep them from reappearing?
I have a 2010 iMac running High Sierra 10.13.5. This may have started when I purchased and connected an external 4 TB drive for backup.

Comment: Did this behaviour coincide with anything else? Can you remember installing new software or purchasing any new hardware around the time this started? Also, what model of Mac are you using and what's the version of macOS installed?

Comment: Did you create a Windows partition by using Bootcamp recently? 31/12/69 is the unix timestamp creation date and I think that EFI is used to install Operating Systems, so can come from there. In that case, I think that you can eject them and they will not come back again.

Comment: no windows partition ever.

Comment: Or at least not intentionally.